# Is it possible for any flow to apply softLock for two users simultaneously to same state?

Tags: corda, softlock

I am trying to softLock a state in the flow as soon as it is fetched from the vault and then running a concurrent request using Jmeter to test this. The issue is, if I run requests for 5 threads, the lock gets applied to same state by 2 threads which leads to Notary Exception. The other 3 threads works fine and throws user defined Flow Exception(which I want to achieve).

```
public void applySoftLock(UUID id, StateRef states, ServiceHub serviceHub, Logger logger) throws FlowException {
        try {
            logger.info("Concurrent Execution - Applying soft lock : " + states.getTxhash().toString());
            logger.info("Concurrent Execution - HASH of the state is : " + states.hashCode());
            synchronized (states){
                serviceHub.getVaultService().softLockReserve(id, NonEmptySet.of(states));
            }
            logger.info("Concurrent Execution - Soft lock applied");
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Concurrent Execution - In progress.Please try after some time. "+ e.getMessage());
            throw new FlowException("Concurrent Execution - Generic Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Below are the logs which is printed after the softLock is applied.

```
February 28th 2020, 12:02:32.096    cordanode   host-dev    06:32:32.095 [Node thread-1] INFO  somepackage.someFlow - Concurrent Execution - State locked: c6a7aa91-eb04-4243-a556-71db955b1d6c  with softLockUUID : 4a1e5cf8-6f36-4c29-bc29-86951ed30b7f
February 28th 2020, 12:02:30.978    cordanode   host-dev    06:32:30.977 [Node thread-1] INFO  somepackage.someFlow - Concurrent Execution - State locked: c6a7aa91-eb04-4243-a556-71db955b1d6c  with softLockUUID : 53e6729c-caaa-45df-b230-a7fb1001ea2d
```

Note: Also tried using `synchronized` block but that didn't help either.

If anyone else faced the same issue or able to solve this, please share any reference or examples on how to avoid the `net.corda.core.flows.NotaryException: Unable to notarise transaction`  and apply softLock successfully.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First, let's think about when is a state being updated? A state will get notarized and updated in the finality flow. It happens in the order of

1) Getting notarized

2) broadcast to parties and record onto ledger

So if any other transaction that is trying to access/change the state, the Notary will rule it as double spend. You wouldn't need a soft lock for the process.

It is not possible to have a racing problem updating the states.